# what is the proper way to save a firebase push notifications sent

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase, push-notification

I'm using firebase push notifications php api with android...
When I send a notification from firebase API, to android device, I also make a MySQL input, to register one copy of that, and work!

but...
What happen when the API sends too many push notifications?
There is no problem with my shared server?
I'm worried that my server will collapse for too many records for each push.

Right now It work like this...

Firebase API PHP send notification  ->  MySQL register that notification in one table -> Android Device recieve the notification.

but I don't think this is the right way...
so... the question is...

what is the proper way to save a firebase push notifications sent...?

Comment: Actually i did in same way. And i saw no problem in that. Only thing is i saved data based on user id in my table. I am keen to look if someone come up with any fresh idea apart from db....

Comment: In my case all notification depends in users so i am saving notification user wise and deleting one one month old notification.